# How to select records with parent child relation having maximum score for a parent

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, greatest-n-per-group

I have tables in like this:

```
ExerciseAttempt(attemptId, ExerciseId, Score, studentId)
ExerciseMeta(ExerciseId, ParentId)
```

Each exercise has one parent. A parent can have many child exercises. Now I want to find the records such that only one child of a parent(the one with max score) is considered.

For example:

**ExericeAttempt:**

```
attemptId | ExerciseId | Score | studentId
1         | 10         |  18   | 10001
2         | 11         |  12   | 10001
3         | 12         |  20   | 10001
4         | 13         |  22   | 10001
5         | 13         |  21   | 10001
```

**ExerciseMeta:**

```
ExerciseId | ParentId
10         |  100
11         |  100
12         |  101
13         |  101
```

For these tables the result should be

```
attemptId | ExerciseId | Score | studentId
1         | 10         |  18   | 10001
4         | 13         |  22   | 10001
```

Also multiple attempts of a same exercise are possible.
How can I achieve this in SQL SERVER?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
 ;with x as (
    select ea.*, em.parentid,
    row_number() over(partition by parentid order by score desc) as rn
    from ExericeAttempt ea
    inner join ExerciseMeta em
    on ea.ExerciseId = em.ExerciseId
)
select attemptId, ExerciseId, Score, studentId
from x
where rn = 1
```

Result:

```
ATTEMPTID   EXERCISEID  SCORE   STUDENTID
1           10          18      10001
4           13          22      10001
```

Result in [**Fiddle**](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/a1510/10).

Comment: (+1) BTW, took the liberty to add the result and fiddle.

Comment: @RagingBull at:dean for http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/ab78c/1 this record its not working

Comment: What "it's not working" means? What result is expected with this data?